# Disable auto focus on edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, autofocus

I have an edit text:

```
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout7" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:text="3">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and then some other stuff underneath

The problem I'm having is that right when the app starts the focus is on the input, i dont want focus to be on input right when the app starts.

I tried removing the

```
<requestFocus></requestFocus>
```

thing and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Set android:focusable="false". It will not focus on your EditText

Comment: that will make un-facusable forever? now even if I click the text field it won't focus. I want to to focus when clicked, just not automatically when the app starts

Comment: you can firstly start with getting id of button and set focus on button in your code....

Comment: I did this:       
a_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_button);
a_button.requestFocus();

right at the begining of the code, but it did nothing. Can i set focus through xml?

Comment: Adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on my **parent layout** works for me.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Add the [`android:focusable="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:focusable) and  [`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:focusableInTouchMode) elements in the parent layout of [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) as follow;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

I think, it should help you.

See also;
    [Android Developers official guide on handling touch and input](https://developer.android.com/guide/input)

Comment: @Saad: It works. I've tested it before posting it here. Keep the element at the top of XML file. BTW, which API level (or Android version) you are developing for?

Comment: good. Can you explain what android:focusable and android:focusableInTouchMode used for(i mean the difference and usage).

Comment: Add this to the parent, as well, if it didn't work:

`android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`

Comment: It works, but when i click on the edittext the keyboard doesn't pops up!

Comment: @reverie_ss you are right i am also experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I had to add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"  for it to work on an Android 19/apk 30 device.  It worked ok on a newer Android 10 device.

Answer (score 23):

If you want clear the default focus on the edit text then use the following 2 attributes

```
android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

inside the parent Linear layout.

for example:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


     <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="email id"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
         android:maxLines="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to hide the keyboard on activity creation use these attributes inside manifest file activity tag
for example:

```
 <activity
     android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>
```

If you want to hide the keyboard on button click or on some event occur use the following code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    //InputMethodManager is used to hide the virtual keyboard from the user after finishing the user input
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage() + ">>");
                }
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage() + ">>");
                }
```

If you want to take off the focus from edit text fields after leaving the activity

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mEmail.clearFocus();
        mPassword.clearFocus();
}
```

And finally If you want to clear the data in the edit text fields on submitting the form use

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mEmail.getText().clear();
        mPassword.getText().clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

NO More work... just add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
to activity tag of the Manifest.xml file .

Comment: Please explain what this does and how it may help the OP. Suggestions without explanation don't help much, even if the fix could work.

Comment: Refer this.. the above link.. .

Comment: That will hide the keyboard, but the EditText still maintains focus, if I recall correctly.

Comment: API 27 all methods mentioned does not WORK!

Answer (score 9):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px" />

 <EditText android:text="" 
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint">
 </EditText>
```

No other coding needed, it's a simple and clear solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window soft input mode hidden for hide keyboard and `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code in LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText

            android:hint="Search..."
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:id="@+id/search_tab_hotbird_F"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyHotbird_F"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="4dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me, wish also will help you.

**Either :**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

add this property to your Manifest.xml file under that specific activity where you want to disable auto focus.
***Cons:*** It will only hide your soft keyboard, will cursor will be still there.

**Else :**

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

add this property to your UI xml file (under parent layout), so that it will hide focus also the keyboard both.

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

detailInputView = (EditText) debugToolsView.findViewById(R.id.input);
    detailInputView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            detailInputView.setFocusable(true);
            detailInputView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: But this also didn't help with taking focus from edit text field, it just change the way element load on device, though it works

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your main layout view xml tag:

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hei [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4286919/lee-han-kyeol),**

There are several way to do this, [Mudassir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476747/mudassir) has give a way to you to do that.

If the idea doesn't work, then do just simple thing-

In your `AndroidManifest>Activity` add this simple code:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Nothing need to do in EditText in XML, all will be work and no focus will appear.

**Look the real life example code:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

for clear default requestFocuse you should set your View's parent focusable="true" like this below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/coordinatorChild"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I make visible the parent view I do this (and it is working fine) Edit text is not focused automatically just if I touch it. (parentView is including edit text)

```
... 
parentView.setFocusable(true);
parentView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
objProperties.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am about 133 months late, but for those wondering, this is what worked for me:

### To stop focus when the layout is inflated

create a random object (i chose a textview) that to small to see and add the XML attributes `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to your code:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/focus_diversion"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

### To unfocus programatically

create an object with the same attributes as above:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/focus_diversion"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

and in Java add request focus whenever you want to unfocus your other view:

```
    TextView decoy_focus = findViewById(R.id.focus_diversion);
    decoy_focus.requestFocus();
```