# Remove auto focus on autocomplete textview

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, autocompletetextview

I am using autocomplete textview and listview in a same page. in the listview, i am using Edittext (dynamically). whenever i am trying to focus on EditText under the listview, it is focusing on autocomplete textview. Please help me to control the focus of two views. how to stop the default focus of autocomplete textview.

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundpattern"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="app.inedge.inedgeactivity.ui.sales.SkuSalesActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_sku_sales"
        android:textColor="@color/header"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_sku"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.75"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="5dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/et_sku"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/et_sku"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:popupBackground="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_sub_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_sku_item_lbl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/sku_it"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sku_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but_addItem_sku"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonorange_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/confirmbutton"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linsku"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_input_name"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Product 1"
        android:textColor="@color/header"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_input_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:ems="5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:imeActionLabel="DONE"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/action_add"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/gray" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add the xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Want to stop focus: You can use `view.clearFocus();`
Want to focus: You can use `view.requestFocus();`

It will helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Add these to the parent view (Linear Layout).

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

This shifts the focus to the parent view.

[This does not work in landscape mode!]

Answer (score 1):

From this other post [Disable auto focus on edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593887/disable-auto-focus-on-edit-text)

Focus the parent layout instead of the edittext

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

if you want to do the same in view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linsku"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple just add this line to your EditText item

```
`android:focusable="false"`
```

like this

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:hint="Write a comment..."
    android:focusable="false"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

Comment: But then the EditText view is no longer focusable, which is not really a solution

Comment: that's not an answer, cause after implemented focusable = false you can't able to type in edittext.